# Ignore all files in folder from Bundle webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm wanting to ignore files in a certain folder form the bundling as they are dynamic requires.

I'm trying to require files like this (I want to ignore these when bundling):

```
require('folder/file' + name)
```

I'm unsure on which method to use in webpack 2.

So far I have tried to use the ignore and loaders sections of the config

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/..app\/*/)
] 

...

loaders: [
    { 
        test: /..\/app\/.*$/,
        loader: 'ignore-loader'
     }
 ],

 ...
```

I have found that these methods often result in failure when bundling/failing to require when the app is run.

It maybe just a case of that my regex is wrong or that I have misunderstood documentation I have read around this area.

Thanks, James

Comment: You're probably looking for the `exclude` option: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/#options

Comment: @TomVanRompaey I have tried adding this in the rules section. Would I need a new rule as i'm currently using the ts-loader.

Comment: rules === loaders. In Webpack 1 (the configuration you are using) this section is called `loaders`, in Webpack 2/3 it's called `rules`. The place where you need to add `exclude` is inside of one of the `rules` (like the rule that will use `ts-loader`).

Comment: Okay, I think I may be confusing my versions then. I'm currently using the latest version as of 15/17/2017. I will remove the loaders property from the config. Thanks!